# How to trigger a segue from a tab bar item to another by clicking a button?

Tags: swift, button, segue, tabview

I am trying to create a Tab View Item inside a Tab View Controller which switches to the other Tab View Items not only by tapping on the item in the Tab Bar but also via a button which I create myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From one of your VCs the tab bar controller, you can access the tab bar controller by accessing `parent`. If your VC is also embedded in a navigation controller, you need to access `parent.parent`.

```
// assuming "self" is embedded in a navigation controller
if let tabBarController = self.parent?.parent as? UITabBarController {

}
```

After you have the tab bar controller, you can set its `selectedIndex` to go to whichever tab you want:

```
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1 // second tab
```

From the docs of [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621171-selectedindex):

> ...Setting this property changes the selected view controller to the one at the designated index in the viewControllers array...

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked for me!